# Thread safety of std::mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, std, mutex

Can I lock `std::mutex` in one thread and unlock it in other thread? This is theoretical question without any specific engineering context. I am just curious.

Comment: No. See also http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutex-vs-semaphore/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ standard, [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]/21 and 22:

> The expression `m.unlock()` shall be well-formed and have the following semantics:
>
> ***Requires*: The calling thread shall own the mutex.**

A violation of requirements in a *Requires* clause induces undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

[cppreference reads:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock)

> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.